# Inside a while loop, check if there are rows that some specify column int is not higher than 0

Tags: php, mysql

**Explanation & Problem**

Okay we have the following columns in our table,

[username] - [message] - [status] - [id]

In some specify PHP page, we use a while loop to post ALL of the rows that are stored in the database.

Okay, but now I want to check if there are any rows in the that table, if not, echo an error.

It's okay, simple as this:

```
$check = $fetch->rowCount();
```

and then

```
if ($check == 0) { }
```

But now, I want to check if column 'Status' is 0.

So if there are no rows with columns 'status' with value 0, it will echo a message.
If there are no rows at all, it will echo a message.

*If there are rows with column 'status' with value 0, it will echo all rows.*

But there are some problems atleast for me, doing so.

**Problem**

I can't do all of the IF statements checks inside a loop, because a loop can't run if there are no rows.

But okay, we can do the check if there are rows outside of the loop, but how would I check if there are rows + they are not with status column holding value higher than '0'?

> **I got it to work somehow, but not like I wanted..**
>
> If there are rows with column 'status' with value 0 + rows with column
>   status with value higher than 0 at same time, it will echo the message
>   + show the rows, which shouldn't work like this!

This is the code I've tried to build:

```
        $check = $fetch->rowCount();
        if ($check == 0) {
            echo '<br /> EMPTY';
        }
        while($row = $fetch->fetch( PDO::FETCH_ASSOC )) {
            if ($check > 0 && $row['status'] == 0) {
                echo 
                '<div class="background">'.$row['email'].' <span style="margin-left: 10px;"><font color="#ff0000">UNANSWERED</font></span><span id="right"><a href="index.php?recover='.$row['recover_id'].'">Read More</a></span></div><br />
                ';
            } else {
                echo 'There are no rows!';
            }
        }
```

Thank you for your help!

Comment: You are checking if $check == 0 but still run the while loop afterwards. You should put an else before the while.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`But now, I want to check if column 'Status' is 0.
So if there are no rows with columns 'status' with value 0, it will echo a message. If there are no rows at all, it will echo a message.
If there are rows with column 'status' with value 0, it will echo all rows.`

Why dont you send that condition to database in your `WHERE` clause

```
SELECT username,message,status,id FROM yourTABLE where status=0
```

So when there are such rows, it will display them. If there are no such rows then you will get your rowcount as 0 and then you can echo the message accordingly

**Tip**

Fetching all rows from a table and then bringing those to PHP only to discard most of them is just like going to a fruit shop buying all the available fruits, bringing them home and then saying Uh no i don't need Oranges,Apples,Apricot etc etc etc. You have to send conditions to your Database, and not bring all data without any condition and then put conditions in PHP.

Comment: Wow.... I haven't thought of this.. So easy fix.. Thanks a lot mate! I  gotta use the WHERE more often now.. so useful.

Answer (score 1):

try this:

```
$check = $fetch->rowCount();
if ($check == 0) {
    echo '<br /> EMPTY';
}
else
{
        while($row = $fetch->fetch( PDO::FETCH_ASSOC )) {
            if ($check > 0 && $row['status'] == 0) {
                echo "status  0";
                // or echo "<br/> BLANK!";
            }
            else
            {
                echo '<div class="background">'.$row['email'].' <span style="margin-left: 10px;"><font color="#ff0000">UNANSWERED</font></span><span id="right"><a href="index.php?recover='.$row['recover_id'].'">Read More</a></span></div><br />';
            }           
       }
}
```

Comment: It fixed the problem, but there's another problem: If I have rows, and all of them has the column 'status' with higher value of '0', it will echo nothing

Comment: I see, you should put the an else after the if inside the while loop. Try edited version.

Comment: So if you also want to show values with status >0 you can modify the `if` in above code and change the `==` comparison to `>=`

Comment: This is a solution, but in my opinion using WHERE stauts = 0 is way stabler and easier. Thanks for your answer too ^^.

Comment: Yeah.. that's a lot easier to hit it at MySQL..:)